# create tablix filter on dataset with multivalue parameter on multivalue field?

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2

I have a list of values in Field and list of values in parameters with comma separation. I want to filter the dataset with parameter list in Filterlist.

Comment: and... your question is what? and your code is where?

Comment: I have a dataset with Field name codes which contain data like '1000,2000,5000' and I m passing a parameter Scode which contain data like '1000,2000,5000,8000'.if first first value of Scode is match then select the row,second on is matched the select the row and so on.But if does't match with any values with parameter then left the row.